validating token provided okta oauth2.0 through introspection
I am trying to validate a token provided by okta for oauth through remote validation method using introspection endpoint but i am getting a error. I have set the introspection end point correctly only, if its wrong please correct me and  help me to solve this problem .
const introspectionEndpoint = 'https://dev-qbxg70o7bq8w0agx.us.auth0.com/oauth2/default/v1/introspect';

 axios.post(introspectionEndpoint, 'accessToken', {
      params: { token: accessTokenString },
      auth: {
        client_id: clinetid,
        client_secret: clientsecret
      }
    })
    .then(response => {
      const data = response.data;
      // If token is active, proceed to the next middleware or route handler
      if (data.active) {
        req.tokenInfo = data;
        next();
      } else {
        return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Invalid access token' });
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error validating token:', error.response?.data || error.message);
        return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
      });

error i am getting : Error validating token: Not found.

Are you sure this is a correct endpoint you are using? Did you consult documentation? I could not find Auth0 describing introspect endpoint

You  can find this endpoint in okta developer  docs

do you care providing a link please?

https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/oidc/

you are looking at Okta product, not Auth0 hence misunderstanding. They are 2 different offerings owned by Okta

One is auth0 and other is?

one is Auth0 and other one is Okta, they have different APIs. Auth0 used to be a separate product until it's been acquired by Okta
